# how many processes are created in this code using fork()

Tags: c++, fork

How many processes does the following piece of code create? Why?

```
int main()
{ 
 fork();
 fork();
 fork();
 return 0;
}
```

I was looking for assitance that said build a tree but i came up with 10 processes but I'm not sure if that is right, i created a tree

Comment: That;s *NOT* a duplicate of the marked question. That's to do with printf buffering and fork().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> main=P1
> ---- first fork
> P1->P1.1
> ---- second fork
> P1->P1.2
> P1.1->P1.1.1
> -----third fork
> P1->P1.3
> P1.1->P1.1.2
> P1.2->P1.2.1
> P1.1.1->P1.1.1.1
> ```

eight.